# How to calculate the sum of a list of integer in Rules

Tags: rules

In a [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) component I have a list of integer (as variable data type). I have to calculate the sum of items and to expose the result. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've been a big user of rules, so I could be wrong, but I don't think there are a whole lot of arithmetic support in general in rules. I believe you'd need to write your own rule for this. (Which could btw be an excellent addition to contrib)

Comment: Hey @Letharion , if you are ever around on drupal.SE again, I'd be interested in your feedback/review of my answer to [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/221032/39516), which is about a field in a field collection (= variation of the list of integers in this question).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I'm honored you'd seek out my opinion specifically. :) Sadly I work very little with Drupal these days, and I fear I can't add much to your answer. It looks rather well written as it is. :)

Comment: @Letharion : merci for your feedback ... anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

1. Add a variable (integer) "total", for example.
2. Loop the list of integers:

   - Calculate a value, input 1: `[total]`, input 2: `[line-item]`, return: "result".
   - Set a data value, data: `[total]`, value: `[result]`.
3. Outside of the loop, the `[total]` value is still available.

Answer (score 0):

this is my suggestion, create the following function in your template file:

```
function <theme>_preprocess_node(&$variables) 
{

}
```

and by **kpr()** function from devel module try to catch where these outputs are positioned in the page array. now you can take them by a **foreach** loop and cast them to integer.

Comment: I don't believe that helps the OP, as the sum should be useful in a _rule_, not just for display.